# Sensitivity analysis question

Tags: sensitivity

I am trying to figure out how to calculate the sensitivity of a circuit, especially the sensitivity of a damping ratio (how much the damping ratio changes as each component value varies).

[image]

Expression for zeta is quite long and complicated, so I prefer not to take partial derivative. I would like to do something like:

calculate the value of zeta when R = 100 ohms.

calculate the value of zeta when R = 101 ohms.

then divide the change in zeta by the change in R.

In this case, how would I normalize this sensitivity value (x/y part)?

Comment: In this case your "y" is zeta and your "x" is R. So just subsitute the values in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case your "y" is zeta and your "x" is R. So just subsitute the values in.

$$S_R^\zeta \approx \frac{R}{\zeta}\frac{\Delta \zeta}{\Delta R}$$

Comment: Would I have to substitute original values or R and zeta for normalizing?

Comment: @user207787, what do you mean by "original" values? You only have two "experimental" values: \$\zeta(R=100)\$ and \$\zeta(R=101)\$. Use those to calculate \$\Delta \zeta\$.

Comment: Sorry, I meant "Would I have to substitute original values *for R and zeta for normalizing?". For R/zeta, do I have to plug in 100 or 101?

Comment: @user207787, if it makes a difference, you should use a smaller difference between your two R values, like 99.9 and 100.1 or something.